# Faster way to color the UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, uiimage, quartz-2d

I am using the below code to color the UIImage and it is working fine. 
But the only problem I am facing is that it is slow. 
I can run this in background thread but for some reason I want to color the image in main thread. 
Is there any other solution which can color the UIImage faster than this solution. Could CIContext help? I would appreciate any help.

```
UIImage *coloredImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
[tintColor setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationIn);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage);
CGContextFlush(context);
coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: You might be faster doing it manually working with raw image bytes on the CPU. Just create a target CGImage, get all 3 pointers and iterate through all 3 buffers in a single loop (that is if all 3 images have the same size). Otherwise you should drop it to GPU (openCL or openGL). It is hard to say if CIContext will be any faster.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you are setting a context size, then filling that size with a color and drawing your image on top of that color.  That means your image has transparency in it.  Have you tried just drawing your image and setting the UIImageView's background color?  The background color will be shown behind the entire image, therefore only being visible where your image has transparency.  That should work.